# AngularJS 1.2 ng-hide animation behavior strange

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a feature that when scrolling, the block hide and when scroll stop, the block show.

And this is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scarletsky/EXgTB/5/).

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $timeout) {
    var topDist, delay;
    var win = angular.element($window);
    win.bind('scroll touchmove', function () {
      topDist = win[0].scrollY;
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        if (topDist <= 0) {
          $scope.status = false;
        } else {
          $scope.status = true;
        }
        $timeout.cancel(delay);
        delay = $timeout(function () {
          $scope.status = false;
        }, 500);
      });
    });
})
```

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: block !important;
}

#test.ng-hide-add, 
#test.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  -o-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  transition:all linear 0.3s;
}

#test.ng-hide-add,
#test.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
 -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:  translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform:  translateY(0);

}

#test.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#test.ng-hide-remove {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform:  translateY(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transform:  translateY(-100px);
}
```

When I stop scrolling, the block should not show immediately. it should execute the ng-hide-remove animation. But the result is not what I want.

The same code running in AngularJS 1.1.5 works well (using ng-animate).

Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, It's my mistake. I miss the `.ng-hide` class. Just add one line:

```
#test.ng-hide,    //add 
#test.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#test.ng-hide-remove {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform:  translateY(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transform:  translateY(-100px);
}
```